# On which OSI-layers does USB work?

Tags: usb

Which layers of the OSI reference model are covered by a typical USB serial interface for connecting local peripheral devices? Which are not covered by USB and why? I am especially interested in layers 6 and 7, but of course I would like to know it for all the layers.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Have you done any research yet, or just asked without trying? For example, USB specs can be freely downloaded from the USB organization website.

Comment: @Justme unfortunatly i'm not in school any more. If i were i would just ask my prof. I had a discussion with my friend over this topic. We both understand what USB is doing on the physical layer and on the data link layer, but we both don't understand what it is doing on the other ones. We have found the USB specs and that's exactly where my question is coming from. I thought USB has nothing to do with the other layers, but it seems that it has. I just didn't understand how and could not understand the relation to the osi-model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61302045/classifying-usb-protocol-in-the-osi-model

Comment: @jsotola hello, i have found out myself some information, but i am not sure if they are correct. I have posted my answer to the question. Thank you for your support!

Comment: The OSI network works on OSI layers. Nobody uses OSI networks any more, they're obsolete. Some of the layers still match up to other kinds of networks, in particular layers 1, 2, 3, 7 and sometimes 4.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what i found out myself. Please correct me if you find any mistakes.

Application Layer: The application on the computer initiates a request to communicate with the USB device. This request is passed down to the lower layers of the network stack.

Presentation Layer: The presentation layer formats the data for transmission, ensuring that it is in a suitable format for the data link layer to transmit.

Session Layer: The session layer establishes and maintains the session between the computer and the USB device.

Transport Layer: The transport layer provides reliable data transfer between the computer and the USB device, handling flow control, segmentation, and reassembly of the data.

Network Layer: The network layer is not involved in communication between a computer and a USB device, as USB is a local communication interface and does not operate at the network layer.

Data Link Layer: The data link layer provides data framing and error detection functionality, ensuring that the data is transmitted over the USB interface without errors.

Physical Layer: The physical layer handles the electrical, mechanical, and functional specifications of the USB interface, transmitting the bits of data over the physical wires of the USB cable.